# HD video streaming via webcam very choppy

Tags: video, streaming-video, webcam

I've tried Cheese and GuvcView, but both are extremely choppy. When I open open GuvcView even if I try and set FPS to 24/sec it only will give me 3 FPS.

I am remoting into the RP3 via TeamViewer. CPU hovers around 95%.

Has anyone had success smoothly streaming webcam video using a RP3 and TeamViewer? If so what program did you use and what settings? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you expect more from an RPi than it can provide.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry. I hope that's not the case. I actually noticed that my Windows machine does the same thing, so maybe it's the webcam? Model is Logitech HD Pro C920.